# pip install ez_setup error: invalid command 'egg_info'

Tags: python, pip, librosa

I use `pip install librosa` but it returns error：

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      C:\Users\forest\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9kubnarv\audioread_290887eadf0e4e15aa16d5ec304ca97a\setup.py:17: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib and slated for removal in Python 3.12; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
        import imp
      D:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

      error: invalid command 'egg_info'
      [end of output]
```

I tryed to upgrade `pip` and `setuptools` but it's no use.And I found a way is `pip install ez_setup` but it still returns error:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      D:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'zip_safe'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      D:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:265: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
         or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
         or: setup.py --help-commands
         or: setup.py cmd --help

      error: invalid command 'egg_info'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.
```

I can't understand how to do next.

Help me.I want this no errors.

Comment: Are you doing this in a virtual environment? What version of Python are you using?

Comment: I use Python 3.10.9. I just use python on Windows, and I enter the code command in Windows powershell.

Comment: Try to update the `distribute` module in admin mode `pip install --upgrade Distribute`

Comment: Thanks, but also failed. Finally I reinstalled Python and it works.